# Android override all button styles except dialogs

Tags: android, android-styles, android-7.0-nougat

I've been overriding the default button style in my app like this:

```
<style name="ButtonStyle" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button">
        <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/primaryTextContrast</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/button</item>
    </style>
```

That worked fine until Nougat, but with Nougat there's been a change (a bug fix I think) such that this style also applies to buttons in dialogs, while in previous versions it did not.  This has the effect of giving the dialog buttons white text on a white background.

In case it's relevant, `button` is a 9 patch in `drawable` and is overridden in `drawable-v21`:

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="?attr/colorControlHighlight">
    <item android:drawable="?attr/colorPrimary"/>
</ripple>
```

The primary color is dark, and `primaryTextContrast` is white.  Dialogs do not get dark buttons in Nougat for some reason - they seem to pick up the text color but not the background.  So I need to either let the dialog buttons do their default thing, or make the buttons fully inherit the style with a dark background and white text.

Comment: Have you found any solution? I am facing the same issue

Comment: No, I have not.

Answer (score 3):

@nasch, Dialog buttons use button bar style. In this scenario, you could do something like

```
<style name="buttonBarButtonStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.ButtonBar.AlertDialog">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

In your main style definition, you then define

```
<style name="MyCustomTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
  <item name="buttonBarButtonStyle">@style/buttonBarButtonStyle</item>
 ...
```

Hope this helps.